# Testing FormControl under Angular invalid and valid

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, form-control

ts:
`budget = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);`

html:

```
<input
    id="budget"
    currencyMask
    placeholder="Dollar"
    [ngModel]="modelService.budget"
    [formControl]="budget"
    value="{{ modelService.budget}}"
    [min]="1.0"
    [options]="{decimal: ',', thousands: '.', allowNegative: false }"
    type="text"
/>
```

spec:

```
it('should not valid', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.budget.setValue(0);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.budget.valid).toBe(false);
}));
```

my test ist always true. How can i patch my budget Value and control to my valid.
0 -> should invalid
10 -> should valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The min attribute on the input element doesn't make the FormControl invalid. Please add the min validator.

```
budget = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1.0)]);
```